What does the inside of an external wall look like?
I want to be able to simulate heat transfer through a wall, and to do that I need to know what the anatomy of the wall I'm simulating is. Preferably be simple e.g 1/2 inch ply wood to 4 in of fiber glass to 3/2 in of drywall. I just need to know what materials and thickness of each material that makes up an external wall.

2 courses of bricks with an air gap, or 2 concrete walls with an air gap, or either with an insulation infill...

what leads you to believe that all walls are designed the same way?
